# I cannot get my imageview uploaded from gallery to stay once the application closes

Tags: java, android

I cannot get my imageview uploaded from gallery to stay once the application closes. I already looked at other questions like this one but it is not working for me. I tried shared pref but it is not working. I might be doing it wrong. Could someone look at my code? I want the imageview uploaded from gallery to stay in the imageview even after the application is closed. I want it to only changed when a new picture is uploaded from the gallery.I have already tried shared preference, but I am pretty sure I did it wrong. It is in the code that I have below. I also used base64.
need help..thanks in advance

here is my code :

```
package com.example.upload;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String TAG = "Hello";
    private Button mButtonChooseImage;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private Uri mImageUri;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
    String imgDecodableString;
    private String selectedImagePath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        mButtonChooseImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_choose_image);

        mButtonChooseImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFileChooser();
            }

        });

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            // for get data from intent

            bitmap = intent.getParcelableExtra("PRODUCT_PHOTO");

            // for set this picture to imageview

            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            sharedPreferences();

        } else {
            retrivesharedPreferences();
        }
    }

    private void sharedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("App_settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
        editor.putString("PRODUCT_PHOTO", encodeTobase64(bitmap));
        editor.commit();
    }

    private void retrivesharedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("MyApp_Settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String photo = shared.getString("PRODUCT_PHOTO", "photo");
        assert photo != null;
        if (!photo.equals("photo")) {
            byte[] b = Base64.decode(photo, Base64.DEFAULT);
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }

    }

    public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image) {
        Bitmap bitmap_image = image;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap_image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

        return imageEncoded;
    }

    private void openFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            mImageUri = data.getData();

            Picasso.get().load(mImageUri).into(mImageView);
            selectedImagePath = getPath(mImageUri);

        }
    }

    private String getPath(Uri mImageUri) {
        if (mImageUri == null) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("AppSharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        selectedImagePath = sp.getString("ImagePath", "");
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        Picasso.get().load(mImageUri).into(mImageView);

        super.onResume();

    }

    public void ff(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want and what you tried. Do you think we will analyse your code to find out?

Comment: I want the imageview (which is uploaded from gallery) to stay in its imageview even after the application is closed. I have already tried shared preference which is in the code that I posted.

Comment: I have edited the question description

Comment: You did not tell what you did with shared preferences and why. You still think we will analyse your code?